# fopen doesn't create a file with date()

Tags: php, html

I have a code which should create a file called "Report (xxxx-xx-xx - xx:xx:xx X.X).txt", but it doesn't creates. I already searched for like 3 hours on a solution for this, but I didn't find any.

Here is the code:

```php
$myfile = fopen("Report (" . date("d/m/Y - h:i:s") . ").txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

(This is on line 34)




And here is the error I get:

```
Warning: fopen(Report (29/07/2020 - 04:35:54).txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\worcome\recibir\index2.php on line 34
Unable to open file!
```

(The "Unable to open file!" text is from the "or die()" part)

Comment: If you try to create a file or folder called "12:00" from Windows explorer you'll helpfully get a list of disallowed characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `/ (slash)`  in the file name and it should work. It is prohibited in file naming. IT is considered `unsafe`

This should do

```
$myfile = fopen("(Report " . date("d-m-Y - h:i:s") . ").txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot! The problematic characters were not just the `/`, the `:` too! Thank you for helping me!